# Learn Dash Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode, learndash

i have a problem with the lesson in learndash wordpress. every time I click "Next" in the lesson section it always appears "please go back and complete the previous lesson" even though I have finished the lesson and require me to return to the previous lesson and click next. I have to repeat every lesson like that. What do I have to do?

I've been looking for references to solve this problem but have not found one. I hope you guys have experience and reference suggestions for me. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to check your course navigation setting. If the course navigation is set to **Linear** mode, a user would need to complete the current lesson to be able to access the next lesson. Whereas, in **Free form** mode, a user can learn any lesson topic in any sequence they want.

**To check the course navigation setting**

1. Navigate to LEARNDASH LMS > COURSES
2. Click on the course you want to edit
3. Click on the Settings tab at the top of the page
4. Locate the section titled “Course Navigation Settings”

If your problem is with the "Mark Complete" button not working, then you can check any theme/ plugin conflicts. You can try changing the theme. If nothing works, you can reach out to support in that case.